# Getting values out of complex Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, associative-array

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party service with a Restful APi (first time doing something like this). I have managed to send the query, get a response from them, and converted it into a JSON array using:

```
$company_json = file_get_contents($3rdparty_url);
$company_array = json_decode($company_json, true);
```

The problem I'm having is getting the values out of this complex array.
This is what the array looks like:

```
{
  "response":{
    "pagination":{
      "next_url":"http:\/\/someurl.org\/companies?limit=25&offset=25",
      "total":33
    },
    "data":[
      {
        "id":"09934451",
        "name":"Acme Incorporated"
      },
      {
        "id":"00435820",
        "name":"Acme Group Limited"
      },
      {
        "id":"06841797",
        "name":"Acme Ltd"
      }
    ]
  },
  "request_id":"570bf0ca96a63"
}
```

I'm able to get the 'name' values out of the array by traversing it with some PHP like this:

```
foreach ($company_array as $data1 => $value1) {
  foreach ($value1 as $data2 => $value2) {
    foreach ($value2 as $data3 => $value3) {
      foreach ($value3 as $data4 => $value4) {
        if ($data4 == 'name') {
            print $value4;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what I really want to do is grab the values and put them into some sort of format like:

```
<ul>
  <li id="09934451">Acme Incorporated</li>
  <li id="00435820">Acme Group Limited</li>
  <li id="06841797">Acme Ltd</li>
</ul>
```

From my searching around it looked like I would be able to do it with something like this, but it doesn't work. The *$value4['id']* & *$value4['name']*, only print out the first letter of the values as if I were using $value4[0]:

```
foreach ($company_array as $data1 => $value1) {
  foreach ($value1 as $data2 => $value2) {
    foreach ($value2 as $data3 => $value3) {
      foreach ($value3 as $data4 => $value4) {
        print '<li id="' .  $value4['id'] . '">' . $value4['name'] . '</li>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think I can be too far off but it's starting to do my head in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your over complicating it, it's very simple...

```
foreach ($company_array['response']['data'] as $data) {
    echo '<li id="' . $data['id'] . '">' . $data['name'] . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly. I had tried several things very close to what you posted, but didn't get it quite right traversing the array!